# Find the required Chi-square score for an arbitrarily low p-value (2 degrees of freedom)

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

I'm trying to use the Chi-Square test to find the significance of data that suffers from the [multiple testing problem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Multiple_comparisons_problem). Because I have this multiple testing problem, the required p-value to view a test as significant is very, very low, around 10E-5. I haven't found a chi-square table that lists critical values that are so low. I'm wondering how I can actually calculate this value myself. Some google searching hasn't helped me find the method with which these chi-square tables are generated.

So:

1. I need to know how to calculate the chi-square values to arbitrarily low p-values.
2. I would like to know how these tables are generated in the first place. The internet tells me they exist and this is how we use them, but not where they come from. It feels a bit deus-ex-machina, like "here's a tool for you, and just trust us that it works."

I'm not a mathematician so an example with the values inserted would be greatly helpful.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions are quite simple to answer. In case of Chi-Square test, the p-value is computed as $1 - CDF_{\chi^{2}_{df}}(ts)$, where $CDF_{\chi^{2}_{df}}$ is a cumulative distributive function of Chi-Square distribution with $df$ degrees of freedom and $ts$ is the value of your test statistic. (Try to figure out why is p-value calculated this way - it is not so difficult).

So, if you want to calculate critical value of Chi-Square test at significance level $10^{-5}$ where test statistic has $\chi^{2}_2$ distribution under null hypothesis, just find the solution of equation $1 - CDF_{\chi^{2}_2}(ts) = 10^{-5}$ in $ts$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found the cumulative distribution function for the chi-square distribution [here](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Chi-squared_distribution), but I don't know how to calculate it (I'm unfamiliar with the symbols). Do you think for the critical value=10^-5 example, you could calculate it through fully? That would at least give me a template to work off and understand.

Comment: Sure. A little problem is that we are unable to write the value in an explicit form (we are able to write it just as a solution of an equation). In example with 10^-5, we have to solve the equation $1-\frac{\gamma(k/2, x/2)}{\Gamma(k/2)} = 10^{-5}$ (where k are degrees of freedom) in x. If you have some clever programme (Mathematica, Maple,...) it is quite easy to solve the equation. Otherwise it is very laborious.

Answer (score 0):

R is a reliable statistical analysis package, widely used in
practice and available free of charge at `www.r-project.org`.
While the package is very broad in scope, you want only a
few simple procedures. Many other computational packages will
do the same thing. Because R is free and reliable, I'll give
instructions for R; adapt them to some other program if you like.

Suppose you want the critical value of a test at level $\alpha = 0.001$
with degrees of freedom $\text{df}= 12.$ The critical value is the value for a chi-squared statistic $Q$ that separated 'fail to reject' to the left from 'reject' to the right. Here is how to use R to
get the answer. (The symbol `>` is the 'prompt'; you don't type that. You can ignore the `[1]` in the result; it is mainly useful for
answers with many parts. You don't need to type anything that
comes after a `#` sign; those are comments for you, not the computer.)

```
 > alpha = .001;  df = 12    # press RETURN at end of each line
 > qchisq(1 - alpha, df)     # notice the 'q' in 'qchisq'
 [1] 32.90949
```

Or you can put the query all on one line, if you like:

```
 > qchisq(1 - .001, 12)
 [1] 32.90949
```

You won't find that value in most printed tables. Here's one you
can compare with a printed table:

```
 > alpha = .10;  df = 8
 > qchisq(1 - alpha, df)
 [1] 13.36157
```

My printed table shows the answer as 13.36, maybe some have 13.362.
R usually prints more decimal places that are really necessary for
your purposes. See illustration below.

If you have a one-sided test in which $\text{df} = 8,$ the
computed value of the chi-squared statistic is $Q = 19.33,$
and you're rejecting for large values of $Q,$ then use can
use R to find the P-value of the test, as follows:

```
 > q = 19.33;  df = 8
 > 1 - pchisq(q, df)    # notice the 'p' in 'pchisq'
 [1] 0.01319102
```

So the P-value is 0.013; small enough to reject at the 5% level
or the 2% level, but not at the 1% level (or lower levels) of
significance.

Compare the following with a printed table and the figure below:

```
 > q = 13.36;  df = 8
 > 1 - pchisq(q, df)
 [1] 0.1000488
```

R is case sensitive. That means it distinguishes between
capital and small letters. For your purposes, you will be happier
if you use lower-case letters for everything, as in my examples above.

END of lesson. That's all there is to it.

These values for the chi-squared distribution are extremely
difficult to compute--essentially impossible to do by hand.
So, in practice, you will have to get over your objection
to the 'deus-ex-machina' existence where the chi-squared
distribution is concerned. Perhaps you have already gotten
over this objection in the case of normal tables (or using
a statistical calculator to get similar values). I imagine
you have never computed those by hand.

In the figure below the blue curve is the density curve of
$Chisq(df=8).$ The vertical line is at 13.36. The entire area
beneath the curve is 1. The area to
the right of the line and beneath the density curve in 0.10.

[image]

---

Note: If you want to give R a try: go the URL given above.
Then click `CRAN` (no idea what that means) and the CRAN site
nearest to you; then your kind of machine (Windows or Mac); then
`base` and `Download`. After a brief time (depending on your
connection speed), an R icon will appear on your desktop; click
it to get the `R Console` window, and start typing at a `>` prompt.